# coloring a complete graph to get scalene triangle, Monochromatic triangle

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, graph-theory, coloring

Let $n$ be a set of color, let $K_m$ be a complete graph , I would like to find a construction that use it to color edges of complete graph such that  monochromatic triangle for each colors appears and scalene  triangle appear inside a complete graph. By other way, color edges of complete graph such that you get a triangle that all its edges color by the same color , and get a triangle that all its edges color by a different color.

Here my trying : I start let $n=4$  four colors , I suppose 7 nodes , then I made the following table but I could not get a general constructions   from the table , here is the table

\begin{array}{c|ccccccc}
\cdot & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 &6&7\\
\hline
1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 &1&2 \\
2 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 4 & 3&1&4 \\
3 & 2 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 3&4&2 \\
4 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 0 & 2 &2&4\\
5 & 4& 3 & 3 & 2 & 0&2&1 \\
6 & 1 & 1 & 4 &2 &2&0&3\\ 7&2&4&2&4&1&3&0
\end{array}

The numbers inside the table mean 1 first color(black), 2 second color(blue), 3 third color(red), 4 forth color(green),so the node(1,2) connect by 1 (black color) , nodes 1, 3 connect by 2 blue color . $0$ mean no color there but you can assume same number instead of $0$ , I mean nodes 1,1 connect by 1 and nodes 2,2 connect by 2 .
I am trying to find a function for the above table , i suppose x and y be nodes of a graph , then I think
(x,y) = ( something )mod 5 , but I could not find the function .
Also , I am thinking to define a group and operation to set up table then, consider the entries in the table  as colors but I am lost in this way.

Comment: A scalene triangle is a triangle whose sides all have different lengths. Somehow I think you are using some other definition of scalene triangle. If you are going to invent your own terminology, you need to explain it so we will know what you're talking about.

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do, for $n=4$ colors, can't you do it with $m=6$ nodes? Color edges $(1,2)$, $(1,3)$, $(2,3)$ black, edges $(1,4)$, $(1,5)$, $(4,5)$ blue, edges $(2,4)$, $(2,5)$, $(2,6)$, $(5,6)$ red, and edges $(3,4)$, $(3,6)$, $(4,6)$ green. So $(1,2,3)$ is a black triangle, $(1,4,5)$ is a blue triangle, $(2,5,6)$ is a red triangle. $(3,4,6)$ is a green triangle, and $(1,2,4)$ is a "scalene" triangle. Is this right, or am I missing something?

Comment: I may be wrong but it seems to me you want to know, for which values of $m$ and $n$ (where $n\ge3$) does the complete graph $K_m$ contain $n$ edge-disjoint triangles? This is answered by the Kirkman–Schönheim theorem [J. Schönheim, On maximal systems of $k$-tuples, *Studia Sci. Math. Hungar.* 1 (1966), 363–368]: $K_m$ contains $n$ edge-disjoint triangles if and only if $$n\le\left\lfloor\frac m3\left\lfloor\frac{m-1}2\right\rfloor\right\rfloor-[m\equiv5\pmod6]$$ where $[m\equiv5\pmod6]$ denotes a quantity which is equal to $1$ if $m\equiv5\pmod6]$ and equal to $0$ otherwise.

Comment: you are right but we have to color every (all) edges of $K_m$ . when you look to above table, I connect all edges. The value of $m$ is open and is better if it is small as we can. $n$ is greater or equal 3. Sometimes,  I think , to divide $n$ to odd number and even number , then find terminology for each.

Comment: In my example I only colored the edges needed for the $4$ momochromatic triangles and the $3$-colored triangle. You can color the remaining $2$ edges any way you like.

Comment: For $n=7$ colors and $m==7$ nodes you can use the [Fano plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fano_plane) (projective plane with $7$ points and $7$ lines).

Comment: Is your method random ? or you have special method which you use it . I am trying to find a general method (general rule) that I  can use it for any number of color .

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you only require one $3$-colored triangle, and not a triangle for every possible combination of $3$ colors?

Comment: It is not just one , could be one and could be more than one.

Comment: I am hardly an expert on this kind of problem, I've already told you everything I know about it, if not more. So I'll go away now, and hope that some expert on combinatorial designs (if that's whhat this is) will come along and give you a good answer.